# I want create query using sum and substarct function in single query using multiple conditions using mysql

Tags: mysql

[image: table ratecard]

In the above table I want to sum where `ledgertype='Earning'` and substract where 
`ledgertype='Deduction'` and display both values..... how to write query?

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Are you after one total value? All Earning - all Deductions?

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve using this. As you wanted to print earnings and deductions as well so I used sub query.

```
select sum_earnings , sum_deduction , sum_earnings - sum_deduction 
from ( select sum(case when ledgertype = 'Earning' then ledgervalue end) sum_earrnings,  sum(case when ledgertype = 'Deductions' then ledgervalue end) as sum(sum_deduction) 
from ratecard ) a
```

Answer (score 0):

I am unable to understand "Both Values" but you can get Aggregate of both types by:

```
Select SUM(ledgerValue), ledgerType FROM ratecard group by ledgerType
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT (SUM_VAL - SUBSTRACT_VAL) as balance FROM
(
 select sum(ledgerValue) AS SUM_VAL FROM ratecard WHERE ledgerType ='Earning', 
 select sum(ledgerValue) AS SUBSTRACT_VAL FROM ratecard WHERE ledgerType = 'substract'
) t1
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Comment: base on this url to get query and removing just limit in this query https://forums.mysql.com/read.php?10,105508,105543#msg-105543

Answer (score 0):

If you want a running total you could use a variable to calculate.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS T;
CREATE TABLE T (ID INT,AMOUNT INT, TYP VARCHAR(10));
INSERT INTO T VALUES
(1,12500,'Earnings'),(2,3200,'Earnings'),(3,1200,'Earnings'),
(4,1200,'Deductions'),(5,200,'Deductions'),(6,600,'Deductions'),(7,500,'Deductions'),
(8,12000,'Earnings'),(9,3200,'Deductions');


select t.*,
         if(t.`typ` = 'Earnings' ,@rt:=@rt+amount,@rt:=@rt-amount) RunningTotal
from t
,(select @rt:=0) rt;
order by t.id

+------+--------+------------+--------------+
| ID   | AMOUNT | TYP        | RunningTotal |
+------+--------+------------+--------------+
|    1 |  12500 | Earnings   |        12500 |
|    2 |   3200 | Earnings   |        15700 |
|    3 |   1200 | Earnings   |        16900 |
|    4 |   1200 | Deductions |        15700 |
|    5 |    200 | Deductions |        15500 |
|    6 |    600 | Deductions |        14900 |
|    7 |    500 | Deductions |        14400 |
|    8 |  12000 | Earnings   |        26400 |
|    9 |   3200 | Deductions |        23200 |
+------+--------+------------+--------------+
9 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```